# Autocomplete dropdown Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the below code I have a HTML autocomplete dropdown which is working fine and when I try to implement as dynamic autocomplete dropdown it is not working.

HTML : It is working Fine

```
<select id="Select1" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Please select a lunchs ...">
    <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
</select>
```

Dynamic Dropdown :Not working it displays as normal dropdown

```
 newdiv.innerHTML += "<select class=\"selectpicker\" data-live-search=\"true\"  data-error=\"Please Provide " + DisplayName + "\" name=\"" + Name + "\" id=\"" + Name + "\"/>";
```

Comment: Can you show your complete dynamic creation code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set the innerHTML, you need to call selectpicker to initialize it.

Try this code after the innerHTML is set

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker()
```